# Flutter Heavy Lifting function during loading

Tags: flutter

I've got a function that takes quite a while to compute (in this case `veryLongFunction` which returns a promise).

```
Future<SomeClass> veryLongFunction() {

  return Future<SomeClass> (() {
    // DO LONG OPERATION HERE
    return result;
  });
}
```

During that time I want to display a loading screen. I've set up the layout so that if `isLoading == True` it will display loading. This should all happen on a button press with this callback:

```
void updateImage() {
  // START DISPLAYING LOADING 
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });

  var promise = widget.object.veryLongFunction();

  promise.then((output) => 
     setState(() {
       _isLoading = false;
     })
  );
}
```

My problem is that I can't get this off the main/UI thread (it still freezes the UI). I've tried to use the `compute` function, but I'm getting the same outcome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us how you used isolate API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use isolate API in case you want to get things off your main thread. please look here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html

Comment: I tried doing `compute ` which should spawn an isolate but it didn't work.